# Inventory Allocation Generic Inquiry Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to create a GI in Acumatica that shows inventory allocations. I already have an inventory allocation details set up in acumatica.

[image]

I want to show only certain fields in a GI. I want to show Allocation Type, Allocation Date, and Qty.

When I try to find the table it turns out to be a temp table or filter.

Is there any way to get around this? I am fairly new at creating gi's, but I have an idea of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter on this page is filled in on entry of the inventory ID, warehouse, location, subitem. Using these DACs in a GI will not work.

You could use some of the IN*Status tables for totals otherwise the INItemPlan table represents the detail in the grid combined with INPlanType for description of allocation type.